# Galvanic corrosion - Relay oxidation?

Tags: relay

[image]

We built a system for heating three bioelectrochemical reactors, but after a certain time of operation (1 month)  the system stopped heating up. We identified that when this occurs, the relay works despite the light being on (indicating that it is activated) while the voltage is at 0 V on the heating strips (added 3.3 A for each strips).

The load of system is AC. The relay I'm using is 5 V, 30 A.

I am trying to understand what could be happening. I decided to look at the inside of the relay and I noticed that it seemed to be oxidized (figure 1), but this isn't possible because it is well protected, besides, it's the only element in the system that shows this 'oxidation'.

Considering that the relay was not exposed to contact with any corrosive substances, how could it have oxidized?

If it is galvanic corrosion, where can I start to solve this problem? The system is inside a box with a lid and a cooler installed.

[image]

Comment: yes, looks like oxidation ... do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Now... what's your question exactly? Your relay got exposed to a corrosive substance that somehow got airborne. (Fine mist from your reactor? Salt spray?) The oxidation is very much possible because it *happened*.

Comment: I find your question rather confusing - you've designed a heating system, and are concerned because it heats up?  Isn't that what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Looks like accelerated galvanic corrosion to me.

Comment: Where did you buy the relay from? Was it a sealed relay? It looks like serious moisture problem. Has the PCB manufacturer cleaned the PCB in water after relay was mounted?

Comment: When relays fail it is almost always the contacts. They could "weld", they could have oxidation, they could get stuck etc. As for the coil it is very sensitive to temperature and voltage changes both, you have to stay within the relay specification at all times. Although in this particular case, if it is just that one relay, it does indeed seem like galvanic corrosion.

Comment: Anyway, to answer I think we need more info. Pictures of how this is mounted, what metals that are used to secure the relay, datasheet of the relay etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Analyze what that green colored corrosion is. If the frame and armature are made of *iron* (not plated with copper), that is *not* oxidation, which would be *red* rust. Are there chlorine compounds in use, such as bleach (hypochlorite or chlorine dioxide) to clean the bioreactor or environment?
2. You state that there is also a *cooler*. Could it cause condensation of moisture from the air onto the relay?
3. It is odd that *all* the other parts in your photos look pristine, even steel bolt heads. Could there be a defect in the relay itself? Could it have been cleaned with bleach before insertion? Is it rated for the current draw (unclear, do you mean the heaters total only 3.3 A)? Is it being pulled in with sufficient current through the coil so that solid contact is made on pull-in?